# Авторизация пользователя vk с помощью cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, вконтакте, curl, авторизация

Добрый день.

Необходимо авторизировать пользователя vk с помощью PHP скрипта и библиотеки cURL. 
Были рассмотрены следующие решения:

- https://forum.antichat.ru/threads/426901/
- http://sauron.org.ua/post/938

На основе решений были составлены следующие скрипты.

Получение значений lg_h и ip_h (работает, получает):

```
$url = 'http://vk.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'origin: http://vk.com',
        'referer: http://vk.com/',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all("/name=\"ip_h\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\//s", $content, $ip_h);
preg_match_all("/name=\"lg_h\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\//s", $content, $lg_h);
```

Отправка запроса авторизации вида:

```
http://login.vk.com/?
act=login&
role=al_frame&
_origin=http://vk.com&
ip_h=$ip_h&
lg_h=$lg_h&
email=<email>&
pass=<pass>
```

Сам скрипт:

```
$url = 'http://login.vk.com/?act=login';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'act' => 'login',
    'role' => 'al_frame',
    '_origin' => 'http://vk.com',
    'ip_h' => $ip_h[0][1][0],
    'lg_h' => $lg_h[0][1][0],
    'email' => '<email>',
    'pass' => '<pass>'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin: http://vk.com',
    'referer: http://vk.com/',
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/home/<user>/Development/vk/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/home/<user>/Development/vk/cookie.txt');

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

На выходе получаю следующее содержимое страницы:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _ua = navigator.userAgent;
var locDomain = 'vk.com'.match(/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.?$/)[0];
if (/opera/i.test(_ua) || !/msie 6/i.test(_ua) || document.domain != locDomain) {
  document.domain = locDomain;
}
parent.__qlClear();
addEvent = parent.addEvent;
vk = parent.vk;
parent.stManager.add(['notifier.js', 'notifier.css'], function() {
  Notifier = parent.Notifier;

  parent.onLoginFailed(4, {email: ''});
});
</script>
```

В свою очередь куки принимают следующие значения:

```
Set-Cookie: remixmid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixsid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixsid6=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixgid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixemail=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixpass=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixapi_sid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixpermit=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
Set-Cookie: remixsslsid=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com
```

Смею предположить, что не удается передать значение email, т.к. в коде JS именно на это и ошибка. При ручном составлении URL и перехода по нему — успешное возвращение хэша и содержимое страницы следующее:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _ua = navigator.userAgent;
var locDomain = 'vk.com'.match(/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.?$/)[0];
if (/opera/i.test(_ua) || !/msie 6/i.test(_ua) || document.domain != locDomain) {
  document.domain = locDomain;
}
parent.__qlClear();
addEvent = parent.addEvent;
vk = parent.vk;
parent.stManager.add(['notifier.js', 'notifier.css'], function() {
  Notifier = parent.Notifier;
    ;(function () {
    var cb = function () {Notifier.init({"queue_id":"events_queueXXX","timestamp":"1947616970","key":"XXX","uid":"XXX","version":9,"debug":false,"instance_id":"XXX","server_url":"http:\/\/q85.queuev4.vk.com\/im824","frame_path":"http:\/\/q85.queuev4.vk.com\/q_frame.php?7","frame_url":"im824","refresh_url":"http:\/\/vk.com\/notifier.php","fc":{"version":23,"state":{"clist":{"min":true,"x": XXX,"y":XXX},"tabs":[],"version":23},"state_hash":"XXX"}})}
    if (window.vk && window.vk.loaded) cb(); else addEvent(window, 'DOMContentLoaded load', cb);
  })();
  parent.onLoginDone('/idXXX');
});
</script>
```

Авторизация проходит успешно. После доступен профиль пользователя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только что написал рабочий код авторизации во ВКонтакте — http://pastebin.com/5YecKuUs

Только учтите, каптча не поддерживается, поэтому сами уже её добавьте.

Тест **успешно** пройден на моём тестовом аккаунте ;)

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает! Буду дебажить-смотреть свой и Ваш вариант, хочется разобраться до конца в чем загвоздка. Премного благодарен! :)

Comment: Может есть у кого рабочая на данный момент версия авторизации - поделитесь пож.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [рабочая библиотека](https://github.com/biganfa/vk-auth) для `PHP`, которая получает куку `remixsid`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Прекрасная библиотека, +rep

Answer (score 1):

По состоянию на июль 2018 это рабочий код. 
Авторизация через мобильную страницу т.к. проще.

```
    $email = "{ТЕЛЕФОН}";
    $pass = "{ПАРОЛЬ}";
    $auth_url = "https://m.vk.com";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $auth_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //файл для сохранения кукис - cookie.txt
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //получаем содержимое формы авторизации (URL атрибута action)
    $login_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //парсим страницу...
    $html = str_get_html($login_page);
    //..и узнаем урл авторизации (использовал библиотеку Simple PHP DOM Parser)
    $login_url = $html->find("form",0)->action;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //отправляем ПОСТ запрос
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //следуем за редиректом
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //данные запроса
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["email"=>$email, "pass"=>$pass]);
    //СНАЧАЛА ЧИТАЕМ КУКИ полученные в первом запросе
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    //потом ДОБАВЛЯЕМ НОВЫЕ
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //пользователь авторизован

    //далее тестируем
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vk.com/groups?act=catalog");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //только читаем куки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //если ваш сервер работает на UTF-8, в отличие от VK (windows-1251)
    echo iconv('windows-1251','utf-8',$page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте закодировать  `<email>` функцией `urlencode`

Comment: К сожалению, эффект тот же.

Comment: Отдельно кодировать email также не приносит желаемого результата, извините :(

Comment: Для уточнения, права на папку `vk` и файл `cookie.txt` выставлены в 777.